# Read and display all file bytes in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to show all the bytes in a .DAT file. I'm completely new to programming and I managed to find how to display the file size correctly but every output byte that I get are 0s even if in HxD the bytes aren't all zero.

What I get:

```
size is: 11
0000000000000000000000
```

What I should get:

```
size is: 11
48656C6C6F20776F726C64
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  //open file and get size
  streampos begin,end;
  ifstream myfile ("TRPTRANS.DAT", ios::binary);
  begin = myfile.tellg();
  myfile.seekg (0, ios::end);
  end = myfile.tellg();
  int n;
  n=(end-begin);
  cout << "size is: " << n<<endl;

  //read file
  vector<char> randomBytes(n);
  myfile.read(&randomBytes[0], n);

  //display bytes
  for (auto& el : randomBytes)
  cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << (0xff & (unsigned int)el);
  cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me fix this and show the bytes correctly thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you seek to the end of the file:

```
  myfile.seekg (0, ios::end);
```

But then you don't go back to the beginning, so the `read` call tries to read from the end of the file, which fails.

Try adding this before the `read` call:

```
  myfile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
```

And also check the error status afterwards:

```
  if (!myfile) {
    cerr << "could only read " << myfile.gcount() << " bytes\n";
  }
```

Comment: A better solution is to not use seeking to determine the file size at all. Ask the OS instead, such as with `std::filesystem::file_size()`, or by using platform APIs directly, like `stat()` or `GetFileSize/Ex()` or `FindFirstFile()`/`GetFileAttributesEx()`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code that avoids looking at file size, using iterator to read the bytes into a char vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{  
    ifstream input("TRPTRANS.DAT", ios::binary);
    //read bytes into vector
    vector<char> bytes(
    (istreambuf_iterator<char>(input)),
    (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    input.close();

    //print bytes as hex
    for (vector<char>::const_iterator i = bytes.begin(); i != bytes.end(); ++i)
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << (0xff & (unsigned int) *i) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you are using the C++11 standard (or later) then you can use the auto keyword to help the readability:

```
for (auto i = bytes.begin(); i != bytes.end(); ++i)
```